# How to modify the application manifest in VSTS release pipeline?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have to add additional parameter to application manifest xml file while deploying to cluster. There is a release pipeline configured in VSTS to which I have to add a task.

How to achieve this ? Should I have to use Powershell inline script ? If so how can I modify file in the artifact directory ?

*@Karthick, Thanks for your answer , but I am facing issues while saving the xml. I did set the Working folder as*  $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

```
$appManifestFile = $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\pkg\ApplicationManifest.xml
$xml = (Get-Content $appManifestFile) -as [Xml]
$newNode = $xml.CreateElement("Parameter")
$newNode.SetAttribute("Name","Test")
$newNode.SetAttribute("Value","Test")
Write-Host $newNode
$xml.ApplicationManifest.Parameters.AppendChild($newNode)
$xml.Save($appManifestFile)
```

As you can see, I am accessing the file directly from the artifacts and then modifying it. This script works fine locally, but in pipeline the file remains unchanged. Am I missing out something?

Comment: what type of application is yours? ,  for windows app you can use mage

Comment: Service fabric application

Comment: Can you share the log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the build events to do that  [How to: Specify Build Events (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx)

**OR**

If you wish to do the same with  VSTS build pipeline, you can add a powershell **buid step** by

**1.** Get the **path** to your artifact drop location

> [image]

**2.** Pass the **path** to your power shell script

> [image]
>
> [image]

***make sure to set the working dir to your artifact drop location. This is where the powershell script will get executed***

3. You need pass the directory as a variable to your PowerShell script, here it is 'appManifestFile'

   > [image]
4. PowerShell script to add append node with '$appManifestFile' as var

> ```
> param
> (
> [string]$appManifestFile = ""
> )
>
> $appManifestFile = $appManifestFile + "\app.manifest"
>
> echo "the path is set to : $appManifestFile"  
>
> $xml = (Get-Content $appManifestFile) -as [Xml] 
> $newNode = $xml.CreateElement("Parameter") 
> $newNode.SetAttribute("Name","Test") 
> $newNode.SetAttribute("Value","Test") 
> $xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($newNode)
> $xml.Save($appManifestFile)
> ```

Comment: Thanks! But I am facing issues while saving the xml. I did set the Working folder as  $(build.artifactstagingdirectory), My code as follows .....

$appManifestFile = $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\pkg\ApplicationManifest.xml
$xml = (Get-Content $appManifestFile) -as [Xml]
$newNode = $xml.CreateElement("Parameter")
$newNode.SetAttribute("Name","Test")
$newNode.SetAttribute("Value","Test")
Write-Host $newNode
$xml.ApplicationManifest.Parameters.AppendChild($newNode)
$xml.Save($appManifestFile)

The file remains unchanged in the artifacts. Am I missing out something?

Comment: @HariPriyaThangavel I have edited the answer with powershell script with variable, you can pass the artifacts drop location as input var to powershell script

Comment: Thanks for your help kartick! I fixed the issue, I was actually changing the files in the staging directory. I executed this before publishing the artifacts which resolved my issue.

Comment: Shouldn't this be done before the build event?