# Copy a file from Azure Blob Storage to TFS Server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

i'm new to TFS server. What i want to achieve :
before or after my `net core` app is released, i want to overwrite a configuration file on the artifact's folder. What is the best `task` to do this with TFS?

Comment: there is no dedicated task for that operation. i'd use powershell-task for that

Comment: thanks, can you provide some examples?

Comment: If you just overwrite the configuration file with another file rather than modify it, copy task with option **Overwrite** is the best way, or you have to use powershell scripts to modify the configuration file on the artifact's folder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505735/how-to-modify-the-application-manifest-in-vsts-release-pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common implementation requirement while working with Azure DevOps.

The marketplace store is flooded with custom tasks that can perform this action.

All you need to do is make changes in the configuration file you want to modify. You have to replace the parts of the file with "__ Value __" format for the values that you want to modify.

For example, if you want to modify the SQL connection string then at the line where you want to modify your connection string instead of the current path set it to __ SQLPATH __ and then use then task mentioned below to replace the value. You can even choose different values for different environments!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=baskarlingamdevops.build-task

There are many other similar FREE options available but this one is my fav. You can explore the rest also.